# Causes for pg_class locks except DROP TABLE

Tags: postgresql, locking, blocking, system-tables

I do experience the following situation on a PostgreSQL 11:

1. A transaction with unknown statements creates an `ACCESS SHARE` lock on `pg_class`.
2. Another connection wants to execute `DROP TABLE` which causes an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on `pg_class`. This operation is blocked because operation #1 still holds the lock.
3. Following that any new connection to the DB is waiting forever, because it needs to access `pg_class` as well.

The only way to proceed is to either kill operation #1 or #2.

While I can reproduce the situation with manual locking the tables, I do not find an explanation what causes the `pg_class` lock on operation #1. That is, `pg_stats_activity` only shows a `SELECT` as current query which is `idle in transaction`. I suspect this not being the statement creating the lock, however.

Thus, any input on what could cause `ACCESS SHARE` locks on `pg_class` except `DROP TABLE` is highly appreciated.

**Update** atm it is also unclear why `DROP TABLE` wants to lock `pg_class`.

Comment: What table is being dropped?

Comment: Some temporary Tableau table. Unfortunately I don’t have any details about it’s definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is caused by a long-running transaction which does a `SELECT` on `pg_class` first. This causes the `ACCESS SHARE` lock.

Typically, `DROP TABLE` does not cause an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, but in that case there is a PG extension loaded which uses more restrictive locking.

Solution for the current situation is to move the `SELECT` on `pg_class` out of the long-running transaction.